# Tips for importing 2D Storyboards for drawing 2D Keyposes?

Tags: animation, import, keyframes, grease-pencil, 2d

New to Blender coming from Adobe Animate, jumping into my first film drawn in it.

I have completed storyboards and am moving into animation. Normally, I would have a storyboard layer and would time them out based on my animatic. Then, lowering the opacity, I would trace over the keys on a new layer and animate from there.

I have learned how to import an image as a mesh, so I can import the panels fine, but I can't figure out how to lay them out on the timeline. Advice would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a year old but I wanted to answer this to allow future help in this topic. I am currently using blender 3.2.0

So what I did was open up a new blender file - **KILL** cube, cam and light. **SWITCH** editor type to video sequencer in viewport, **ADD** > movie, and **SELECT** *"animatic file.mp4"* & **ENTER**. In *Sequencer* **SELECT** audio clip portion of your animatic file and  **Press** **N** to show *Sidebar* *(if not already shown)*. In *Sidebar*, under the strip tab, **CLICK** on *Sound* option and **CHECK** display waveform. **Collapse** the *Sound* option, and under *Time* option, make sure your clip start is at frame 1 *(or whatever suits your need)*. **CTRL + MIDDLEMOUSE click** and **drag** up or down to zoom clip and **SHIFT MIDDLEMOUSE & DRAG** to pan clip as needed. On the upper right of video sequencer editor **CHECK** thumbnails option under show overlays for *sexy*. **CLICK** on the *View* option on top of sequencer and **CHECK** the Channel option. **LOCK** both audio and video channels on left. You can rename channel as you like.

Now **SPLIT** viewport area and **SWITCH** editor type to *Timeline* on newer viewport. **CLICK** on *Playback* option and **SELECT** *Sync to Audio* next to *Sync* option & **CLICK** on checkbox next to *Scrubbing* option. **ADJUST** *End frame* to match your needs.

**SHIFT A** or **CLICK** *Add* on *3D Viewport* & **ADD** Empty > Image. In *Properties* editor type, **SELECT** *Object Data Properties* tab and under *Image* section, drop down, **SELECT** and **OPEN** your *"animatic file.mp4"*. In the same *Image* section  **ADJUST** your Frames so that it matches your needs. Make sure Auto Refresh is **CHECKED**. In 3D viewport hit **R**, **X** type **90** & **ENTER** to rotate your animatic to view. Hit **Numpad 1** for *front view*. Hit **G**, **Z** & and **Move** animatic up so that the base of it lines up with 3D floor *(Hit N to bring up toolbar and CHECK Lock to 3D Cursor for help lining things up).* In *Outliner* **RENAME** *Empty* object into *"Animatic"* and **CLICK** on *disable selection in viewport* on right *restriction toggles* to prevent accidental movement (Click on Filter option on top of Outliner and turn on this, if you do not see the toggle).

Now make sure you are still on front view and hit **SHIFT A**, **ADD** *Camera* object. Hit **G**, **Y** and **Move** camera back to be in front of Animatic. Hit **Numpad 0** to go into camera view and hit **G, Z** and move camera up and **G, Y** to move cam closer. Hit **G** & **Move** until camera frame matches animatic frame. Go to *Output Properties Tab* in *Properties Editor* and make sure Resolution and Frame rate matches your Animatic's format.

**CREATE** another *Area* and **SWITCH** editor type to *Dopesheet* and **CHANGE** *Dopesheet* context option to *Grease Pencil*. **MAKE** sure you are on frame 1 on timeline. **SHIFT A** to ADD > Grease Pencil > Stroke. In *3D view* **GO** upper right to *Viewport Overlays* toggles, **CLICK** on dropdown arrow & **CHECK** box next to *Canvas* option *(down at Grease Pencil section)*. You should now see a *Grid* over your *Stroke*. **GO** to object data properties and go down to *Canvas* section and **ADJUST** Color, scale etc to your needs. With *Grease Pencil* object selected, hit  **G**, **Z** and **MOVE** up Stroke until base of grid is right on top of 3D floor.

**SWITCH** to *Draw Mode* and erase **Stroke**. **SCRUB** through animatic and begin storyboarding. Make sure *Autokeying* is active in playback timeline. If animatic is way to bright **SELECT** animatic object and in *Object Data Properties* tab, **CHECK** Opacity and **ADJUUST** as needed. **GO** up right in 3D viewport and **CLICK** dropdown on *Viewport Shading* & under Background **SELECT** *Viewport* option and **CHOOSE** brighter color to further dim animatic.

This is how I did my setup and hopefully it still is of help to you. Hope you never give up! Love!